# Show that sum and product are both examples of accumulation

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp

Given this task:

> **Exercise 1.32**
>
> a. Show that sum and
>   product (exercise 1.31) are both
>   special cases of a still more general
>   notion called accumulate that combines
>   a collection of terms, using some
>   general accumulation function:
>
> (accumulate combiner null-value term a
>   next b)
>
> Accumulate takes as arguments the same
>   term and range specifications as sum
>   and product, together with a combiner
>   procedure (of two arguments) that
>   specifies how the current term is to
>   be combined with the accumulation of
>   the preceding terms and a null-value
>   that specifies what base value to use
>   when the terms run out. Write
>   accumulate and show how sum and
>   product can both be defined as simple
>   calls to accumulate.
>
> b. If your accumulate procedure
>   generates a recursive process, write
>   one that generates an iterative
>   process. If it generates an iterative
>   process, write one that generates a
>   recursive process.

I wrote the following solution:

Recursive:

```
(define (accumulate combiner null-value term a next b)
  (if (> a b) null-value
      (combiner (term a) 
                (accumulate combiner 
                            null-value
                            term 
                            (next a) 
                            next 
                            b))))
```

Iterative:

```
(define (i-accumulate combiner null-value term a next b)
  (define (iter a result)
    (if (> a b) result
        (iter (next a) (combiner (term a) result))))
  (iter a null-value))
```

Sum/Product using iterative accumulate:

```
(define (sum term a next b) (i-accumulate + 0 term a next b))
(define (product term a next b) (i-accumulate * 1 term a next b))
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the only parameter that changes in your recursive definition is `a`, you can write an inner definition like so:

```
(define (accumulate combiner null-value term a next b)
  (define (rec a)
    (if (> a b)
        null-value
        (combiner (term a) (rec (next a)))))
  (rec a))
```